# Getting System.EntryPointNotFoundException: _monodroid_get_dns_servers in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I'm trying to get DNS servers of an Android device.

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
...

NetworkInterface[] interfaces = null;
try
{
    interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
}
catch (NotImplementedException)
{
    return 0;
}

foreach (NetworkInterface inter in interfaces)
{
    if (inter.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
    {
        IPInterfaceProperties interProperties = inter.GetIPProperties();
        IPAddressCollection dnsHosts = interProperties.DnsAddresses;
        foreach (System.Net.IPAddress dnsHost in dnsHosts)
        {
            servers.Add(dnsHost.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The code throws EntryPointNotFoundException with "_monodroid_get_dns_servers" message when interProperties.DnsAddresses is accessed.

My Xamarin is the latest (Xamarin.Android 7.1.0), the emulator runs Android 6.0 API 25 (Android 4.4 API 19 - the same issue).

Can I do anything to overcome this issue and get the DNS servers for this device?

The detailed Output from Xamarin (stack trace, etc):

```
Loaded assembly: System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll [External]
04-14 08:42:04.761 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/libc.so'.
04-14 08:42:04.761 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/libc.so'.
04-14 08:42:04.761 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libc.so' ('/system/lib/libc.so').
04-14 08:42:04.761 D/Mono    ( 6644): Searching for 'uname'.
04-14 08:42:04.761 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing 'uname'.
04-14 08:42:04.761 D/Mono    ( 6644): Found as 'uname'.
04-14 08:42:04.782 D/Mono    ( 6644): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xacbf1340] -> System[0xad9bf1c0]: 9
04-14 08:42:04.783 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
04-14 08:42:04.783 D/Mono    ( 6644): Searching for '_monodroid_getifaddrs'.
04-14 08:42:04.783 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_getifaddrs'.
04-14 08:42:04.783 D/Mono    ( 6644): Found as '_monodroid_getifaddrs'.
04-14 08:42:04.788 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
04-14 08:42:04.788 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
04-14 08:42:04.788 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
04-14 08:42:04.788 D/Mono    ( 6644): Searching for '_monodroid_get_android_api_level'.
04-14 08:42:04.788 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_get_android_api_level'.
04-14 08:42:04.788 D/Mono    ( 6644): Found as '_monodroid_get_android_api_level'.
04-14 08:42:04.797 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
04-14 08:42:04.797 D/Mono    ( 6644): Searching for '_monodroid_freeifaddrs'.
04-14 08:42:04.797 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_freeifaddrs'.
04-14 08:42:04.797 D/Mono    ( 6644): Found as '_monodroid_freeifaddrs'.
04-14 08:42:11.521 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
04-14 08:42:11.521 D/Mono    ( 6644): Searching for '_monodroid_get_network_interface_up_state'.
04-14 08:42:11.521 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_get_network_interface_up_state'.
04-14 08:42:11.521 D/Mono    ( 6644): Found as '_monodroid_get_network_interface_up_state'.
04-14 08:42:14.731 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
04-14 08:42:14.731 D/Mono    ( 6644): Searching for '_monodroid_get_dns_servers'.
04-14 08:42:14.731 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_get_dns_servers'.
04-14 08:42:14.731 D/Mono    ( 6644): Could not find '_monodroid_get_dns_servers' due to 'Could not find symbol '_monodroid_get_dns_servers'.'.
04-14 08:42:14.731 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_get_dns_servers'.
04-14 08:42:14.731 D/Mono    ( 6644): Could not find '_monodroid_get_dns_servers' due to 'Could not find symbol '_monodroid_get_dns_servers'.'.
04-14 08:42:14.731 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA'.
04-14 08:42:14.731 D/Mono    ( 6644): Could not find '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA' due to 'Could not find symbol '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA'.'.
04-14 08:42:14.731 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA'.
04-14 08:42:14.731 D/Mono    ( 6644): Could not find '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA' due to 'Could not find symbol '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA'.'.
04-14 08:42:14.732 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
04-14 08:42:14.732 D/Mono    ( 6644): Searching for '_monodroid_get_dns_servers'.
04-14 08:42:14.732 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_get_dns_servers'.
04-14 08:42:14.733 D/Mono    ( 6644): Could not find '_monodroid_get_dns_servers' due to 'Could not find symbol '_monodroid_get_dns_servers'.'.
04-14 08:42:14.733 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_get_dns_servers'.
04-14 08:42:14.733 D/Mono    ( 6644): Could not find '_monodroid_get_dns_servers' due to 'Could not find symbol '_monodroid_get_dns_servers'.'.
04-14 08:42:14.733 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA'.
04-14 08:42:14.733 D/Mono    ( 6644): Could not find '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA' due to 'Could not find symbol '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA'.'.
04-14 08:42:14.733 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA'.
04-14 08:42:14.733 D/Mono    ( 6644): Could not find '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA' due to 'Could not find symbol '_monodroid_get_dns_serversA'.'.
04-14 08:42:15.696 I/Choreographer( 6644): Skipped 881 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
An unhandled exception occured.
04-14 08:42:17.985 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
04-14 08:42:17.985 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
04-14 08:42:17.985 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
04-14 08:42:17.985 D/Mono    ( 6644): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
04-14 08:42:17.985 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing '__android_log_print'.
04-14 08:42:17.985 D/Mono    ( 6644): Found as '__android_log_print'.
04-14 08:42:17.995 I/MonoDroid( 6644): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
04-14 08:42:18.020 I/MonoDroid( 6644): System.EntryPointNotFoundException: _monodroid_get_dns_servers
04-14 08:42:18.020 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Net.NetworkInformation.UnixIPInterfaceProperties:_monodroid_get_dns_servers (intptr&)
04-14 08:42:18.020 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.UnixIPInterfaceProperties.GetDNSServersFromOS () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/3a62f1ea/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/IPInterfaceProperties.cs:64 
04-14 08:42:18.020 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.UnixIPInterfaceProperties.get_DnsAddresses () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/3a62f1ea/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/IPInterfaceProperties.cs:149 
04-14 08:42:18.020 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at MyLibrary.DnsDetector.LoadDnsServersFromNetworkInterface (MyLibrary.DnsServerCollection servers, System.Boolean skipIPv6) [0x00041] in C:\MyLibrary\DnsDetector.cs:315 
04-14 08:42:18.020 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at MyLibrary.DnsServerCollection.Autodetect (MyLibrary.DnsAutodetectOptions options) [0x0009a] in C:\MyLibrary\DnsServerCollection.cs:153 
04-14 08:42:18.021 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at MyLibrary.DnsServerCollection.Autodetect () [0x00001] in C:\MyLibrary\DnsServerCollection.cs:115 
04-14 08:42:18.021 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at XamarinAndroidApp.MainActivity+<>c__DisplayClass5_1+<<OnCreate>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x001ff] in C:\!Projects\XamarinAndroidApp\MainActivity.cs:117 
04-14 08:42:18.021 I/MonoDroid( 6644): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
04-14 08:42:18.021 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/3a62f1ea/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
04-14 08:42:18.021 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/3a62f1ea/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 
04-14 08:42:18.021 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at Android.App.SyncContext+<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/3a62f1ea/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:35 
04-14 08:42:18.021 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/3a62f1ea/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36 
04-14 08:42:18.021 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/3a62f1ea/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-25/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81 
04-14 08:42:18.021 I/MonoDroid( 6644):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:a1a06d03-dca2-4057-bae3-40693822ebf6 (intptr,intptr)
04-14 08:42:18.038 W/art     ( 6644): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable
04-14 08:42:18.045 D/Mono    ( 6644): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
04-14 08:42:18.045 D/Mono    ( 6644): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
04-14 08:42:18.046 D/Mono    ( 6644): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
04-14 08:42:18.046 D/Mono    ( 6644): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
An unhandled exception occured.
```

Comment: On which line did you get this exception? I tested your code, commented the part inside `foreach` since I don't know your `skipIPv6`, `IsIPv6OrInvalidAddress` and `servers`, your code runs well by my side.

Comment: "IPAddressCollection dnsHosts = interProperties.DnsAddresses;" - this line. Working fine on Windows, crashes on Xamarin. I now removed skipIPv6 part of code which is not relevant to the case (thanks for the point).

Comment: I tested on android 6.0 and 7.0 emulator, works fine.

Comment: I added Output from Xamarin. Maybe this can help somehow?